# Sourcegraph VSCode - A patternType: filter is required in the query for all saved searches

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, sourcegraph

I am trying to save search query in sourcegraph vscode extension.

Name: "Master Search"
Query: "context:global repo:^teams/master$ getSiteSettings"

Clicked "Add saved search"

Error:

```
A patternType: filter is required in the query for all saved searches. 
patternType can be "literal", "regexp" or "structural"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `patterntype:regexp` to the end.

`"context:global repo:^teams/master$ getSiteSettings patterntype:regexp"`

[image]

Comment: Also apologies for the delay, I was out sick yesterday.